# Man command does not work with yelp

Tags: 13.10, manpage, yelp

When I was introduced with Ubuntu 8.04, the Yelp (Ubuntu documentation) was aware of `man` command: simply type `man:<manpage>` into the search string showed the desired man page in HTML look and feel. However, since release 13.04 this feature looks like has been removed.

[image: missing feature]

Here is the screenshot of Yelp from 10.04:

[image: yelp 10.04]

Does anyone know how to turn it back?

Comment: OK, I did [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yelp/+bug/1298210). Still awaiting for workaround…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. They just change the manner how to search man pages.

You can solve this by this trick: :)

**Open yelp**

[image]

**Then when pressing on the search field**

[image]

**press ctrl+L**

[image]

**Then remove the keywords "help" or "help-list". Be sure you clean up the address**

[image]

**now you can enter man:bash**

[image]

**Enjoy**

[image]

Comment: nice catch! I came until the ctrl-L, but missed the last step

Comment: This might still be considered a bug (or a *feature request*) if the logic of the current way wouldn't be broken by allowing "legacy" manpage searches to work as they did before. (Btw, great answer!)